# TabControl without border wpf (XP)

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I'm experiencing a visual issue with styling a TabControl in WPF. So even if I set the border of the tab control to be 0px and transparent there is still a very thin line on the right and bottom borders.

I didn't manage to find the property which would resolve that, so maybe someone experienced the same issue and could share it.

Thanks in advance, 
Boris

Comment: I also get a visual issue with a TabItem. When you set the Border and the Background with the same color, and they have a corner radius, the  inner corners (inside the border) the content won't be completely fill. In my case there is still some white in the corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure its part of the border and not the DropShadowEffect?

You'll have to override the ControlTemplate to get rid of the border completely. Heres an [MSDN Example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx)

Comment: The Border named 'Border' inside the TabControl's ControlTemplate is surrounding the ContentPresenter, and putting the border around the TabItem's content, the Border properties on the TabControl won't effect this, so you have to modify the ControlTemplate to remove that border.